# Swift как сделать умножение строк/массивов на число?

Tags: swift

Например в Python можно сделать нечто подобное:

```
"Text" * 3 // Вернет "TextTextText"
```

Или

```
[1] * 3 //Вернет [1,1,1]
```

Как сделать такое в Swift? И как вообще это называется?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я не ошибаюсь, то нативного подхода не существует. Можно создать массив элементов с определенным количеством базового элемента.

```
Array(repeating: "1", count: 3) //["1", "1", "1"]
```

Либо писать **generic**

```
func multiplication<T> (value: T, _ count: Int) -> String {
  var string = ""
  for _ in 0..<count {
    string += "\(value)"
  }
  return string
}

multiplication(value: "Hello", 5) //"HelloHelloHelloHelloHello"
multiplication(value: 1, 5) //"11111"
```